# Soccer team lineup announcement time

Tags: rules, football, english-premier-league

Ignoring player positions, Is there a time by which a soccer team lineup has to be announced? I'm looking at English Premier League in particular.

I.e. Is it known at least X minutes before kick-off or can it be left unannounced and unknown until the players come onto the pitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to rule L.21 of the current [Premier League Handbook](https://www.premierleague.com/publications):

> **At least 75 minutes** before the time fixed for the kick-off of a League Match, a
>   representative of each participating Club shall submit a team sheet by such method
>   as approved by the Board containing the following particulars:
>
> - the shirt numbers and names of its Players (including substitute Players)
>     who are to take part in that League Match;
> - the colour of the Strip to be worn by its Players, including the goalkeeper;
>     and
> - the names and job titles of up to seven Officials who will occupy the trainer’s
>     bench during that League Match